# Not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently (key App plays audio)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have my v 1.1 of my app (iphone) which has been rejected from Apple.

Reasons for rejection:

---

> 2.16
>
> We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include
>   functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This
>   behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for audio in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but no audible content is
>   played when the application is in the background. While your intention
>   may have been to provide this functionality, at the time of review, we
>   were not able to play background audio for your app.
>
> As indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide: "This key is
>   intended for use by applications that provide audible content to the
>   user while in the background, such as music-player or streaming-audio
>   applications." Therefore, it would be appropriate to provide audible
>   content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the
>   "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

---

In the v 1.0 which has been accepted the required background mode "App audio plays" was already enable.

When I launch one sound of my app the sound is played and I when click on the lock screen the sound continues to be played in background.

In the new version (v1.1) I added the function which detects when I push the button Home of the iPhone. If the button home is pressed so the sound is paused.

When i try on my device it's run correctly and without bug.

So I don't understand exactly what is the problem with my app?

Answer (score 1):

If you're pausing the sound when you hit the home button, then you aren't playing a sound in the background. Either change your app so that it plays sound in the background all the time, or email Apple and explain that your app needs the background functionality so that it can play while the phone is locked.

I'm not sure but you might be able to play the sound during the lock screen without audio background mode. Try removing it and see if your app behaves the same. If it does, then you should remove the key (no reason to have it).

Comment: Ok this is what I thought. I tried to email Apple and explain them that I need background functionality and i'm waiting for a answer. Yes it seems possible with beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler like said Ashley Mills but for the moment I have not succeeded.

Thank you both !!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the audio background mode, your app has to play continuous audio (like the Music app, or Downcast for example). Is that what yours does? Or does it just play a sound briefly?

You should be able to play a short sound (< 10 mins) by using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` (I think!)

Comment: It play a sound not more than 5 minutes by sound.
I used AVAudioPlayer.

I tried to use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: but it doesn't work for the moment.

Answer (score -1):

See below the answer to my Question from Apple :

Jul 31, 2012 10:21 AM. From Apple.

**Hello,**

**Thank you for providing this information. However, in order to ensure that the audio background feature is properly implemented, it would be appropriate to press on the home button once the audio is launched.
For more information on how to implement this feature, please refer to iOS Application Programming Guide
Please make necessary change to resolve this issue.**